# Thinktecture ResourcAuthorization, no AuthorizationManager set

Tags: c#, thinktecture

I am trying to build a sample web application using the Thinktecture sample [ResourceAuthorization](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/OWIN/ResourceAuthorization) from github.

Now I have an action in the controller decorated with authorize attribute:

```
[ResourceAuthorize("Edit", "Resource")]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

---

I implemented my own AuthorizationManager:

```
 public class AuthorizationManager : ResourceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override Task<bool> CheckAccessAsync(ResourceAuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;

        if (resource == "Resources")
        {
            return CheckResourcesAccessAsync(context);
        }
        else
        {
            return Nok();
        }
    }
```

When I try to run my application now I keep getting the error:

```
No AuthorizationManager set.
```

---

I thought maybe I have to register the manager in the web.config like this:

```
 <system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration>
    <claimsAuthenticationManager type="Namespace.xy.AuthorizationManager, Namespace.xy" />
</identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to register the authorizationmanager in the startup:

```
 app.UseResourceAuthorization(new MyAuthorizationManager());
```

Comment: Also, it must be registered BEFORE registering the Web Api with app.UseWebApi(config). Otherwise you'll get the same error, as stated here: https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/issues/122#issuecomment-103945807

Comment: This comment of Mahmoud Ali is very important and solved the problem for me.